# Jenkins Global Pipeline Library dir structure

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

What is the proper dir structure for a Jenkins global pipeline library project? I'm new to groovy and want to make sure i'm setting this up correctly from the start...

```
src/com/myco/pipeline/lib_name/...
vars/...
resources/com/myco/...
```

Does this look correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

1- Global variables (.groovy files under vars/) must be added directly at vars' root directory i.e vars/ must not have sub-directories

2- Make sure to add "package com/myco/.../lib_name" at top of your classes (.groovy files) under src/

For more details, please see
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Comment: perfect, thanks. not sure how i missed this in the doc ;)